# Complexidade de Processamento em um Dataframe do Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estou precisando lidar com um problema de junção de bases na linguagem Python. Eu possuo três camadas de pastas que eu preciso entra, encontrar o arquivo e mesclar em um dataframe. Sendo as camadas: ano, mês e dia. Os arquivos que contém os dados são do tipo `.txt` e estou interpretando o algoritmo no `Jupyter Notebook`. O algoritmo para juntá-las eu já fiz. Vou tentar apresentar por partes.

Primeiro eu obtenho as **pastas** do diretorio que contém os **anos**:

```
# Directory
os.chdir('diretorio')

# Moving first layer - year
lista_dir1 = [f for f in glob.glob('20*')]
lista_dir1.sort()
lista_dir1
```

Após criar uma lista com as pastas do diretório, eu faço um *loop* para percorrer cada elemento da lista e mapear as **pastas** dos **meses** de cada ano:

```
contador = 0

for t in range(len(lista_dir1)):
    prim_cam = "diretorio" + '/' + lista_dir1[t] 

    os.chdir(prim_cam)

    lista_dir2 = [f for f in glob.glob('*')]
    lista_dir2 = list(map(int, lista_dir2))
    lista_dir2.sort()
    lista_dir2 = list(map(str, lista_dir2))
```

Após entrar no ano, mepear as pastas dos meses e criar uma segundo lista esses meses, eu entro em cada mes e procuro as **bases de dados** dos **dias**, criando uma terceira lista com os dias:

```
for p in range(len(lista_dir2)):

        segun_cam = prim_cam + '/' + lista_dir2[p]
        print(segun_cam)

        os.chdir(segun_cam)

        lista_dir3 = [f for f in glob.glob('*')]
        lista_dir3 = list(map(int, lista_dir3))
        lista_dir3.sort()
        lista_dir3 = list(map(str, lista_dir3))
```

Por fim, seleciono cada **base de dados**, obtenho os dados e mesclo em um dataframe:

```
for y in range(lista_dir3):
            dados = open(lista_dir3[y])
            yourList = dados.readlines()


            if((t == 0) and (p == 0) and (y == 0)):

                dados_compl = pd.DataFrame(columns = list(yourList[0].split(',')))

                for l in range(1,len(yourList)):
                    dados_compl.loc[l + contador*1440] = list(yourList[l].split(',')) 
                contador += 1

            else:

                for l in range(1,len(yourList)):
                    dados_compl.loc[l + contador*1440] = list(yourList[l].split(',')) 
                contador += 1
```

Ainda, eu fiz um contador chamado de `contador` para indexar meu dataframe.

Bom, agora vêm as perguntas.

**1.** Eu estou utilizando jupyter notebook e o processo tem sido demorado, existe diferença de processamento caso eu rode o programa em um outro interpretador de Python?

**2.** As colunas do meu dataframe são do tipo object

```
Date                     object
Time                     object
Global_active_power      object
Global_reactive_power    object
Voltage                  object
Global_intensity         object
Sub_metering_1           object
Sub_metering_2           object
Sub_metering_3\n         object
dtype: object
```

seria aconselhável eu transformar as númericas para `float`, isso tornaria meu processamento mais rápido?

**3.** Eu utilizei essas funções

```
dados = open(lista_dir3[y])
                yourList = dados.readlines()
```

para fazer a leitura dos dados, será que haveria uma alternativa mais eficiente?

**4.** O que é um tipo de dados `object`? Eu programo muito em R e não recordo de ter visto esse tipo de dados.

Atenciosamente!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resumindo meu entendimento:

Vc tem arquivos armazenados em algum lugar em **base dir**/year/month/day/**some file.txt** (ou seria csv ?) e precisa mesclar os dataframes derivados desses arquivos txt de forma mais rapida.

Eu nao sei exatamente se vai ficar mais rapido mas posso te dar alguma ideias.

1. Relacionar o item utilizar apenas os arquivos na faixa de data (nao sei se vc ja esta fazendo isso)
2. Utilizar a funcao pandas.concat para juntar data frames atraves de linha ao inves de iloc (nao sei se eh mais rapido)

Veja referencia aqui: https://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf

Abaixo segue uma sugestao de codigo:

```
base_dir = '<diretorio base dos arquivos>'

df = pd.Dataframe()

for year in range(year_init, year_end + 1):
  for month in range(month_init, month_end + 1):
    for day in range(day_init, day_end + 1):
      full_filename = base_dir + '/' + year + '/ + month + '/' + day + '/' + filename # tem como saber o nome do arquivo dentro do diretorio ?
      new_df = pd.read_csv(full_filename)
      df = pd.concat(df, new_df)
```